# using react redux reducer ends up stalling the browser

Tags: javascript, reactjs, redux, react-redux

so I have this code

```
const changeCategory = (state = {}, action) => {
  return Object.assign({}, state,
    {
      activeCategory: 1
    }
  );
}


function daReducer(state = {}, action){
  switch(action.type){
    case 'CHANGE_CATEGORY':
      return changeCategory(state, action);
    default:
      return state;
  }
}

export default daReducer;
```

and on another jsx

```
let store = createStore(daReducer, initialState);

render(<Provider store={store}><da/></Provider>, document.getElementById('app'));
```

which works properly

But then if I modify the value of activeCategory to an object:

```
const changeCategory = (state = {}, action) => {
  return Object.assign({}, state,
    {
      activeCategory: {id: 1}
    }
  );
}
```

Running it in Firefox end up returning "Warning Unresponsive Script" error

Why does that happen and how do I resolve that?

Comment: Can you show your `<da>` component? Nothing looks broken in the code you've posted.